# Setting Arabic text in Toast issue Android

Tags: android, android-toast, arabic-support

I am displaying a Toast with Arabic text in my app. I've added the Arabic in my strings.xml file like

```
 <string name="gathering_locations">أماكن التجمعات . هذا قد يستغرق بضع ثوان</string>
```

In strings.xml, it seems right but when the Toast is displayed, the message is shown like the second sentence is shown first and first one is shown as next sentence. How to fix this?? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: arabic is read from right to left.. it may have something to do with that.

Comment: have you added `android:supportsRtl="true"` to `<application>` tag in your manifest ?

Comment: @AbhishekBansal still not working :(

Comment: try setting one of these variables on your toast to `rtl`
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:layoutDirection

or 

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:textDirection

Comment: Could you please show me an example of that??

Comment: I dont have an example as of now but here is my source 
http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html

Comment: I want to display this in Toast. Not in any other view. Is this same as that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116341/discussion-between-abhishek-bansal-and-jas).

Answer (score 2):

```
Toast toast = 
Toast.maketext(getApplicationContext(),R.string.gathering_locations,
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
TextView tv = (TextView) toast.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
if (tv != null) tv.setTextDirection(View.TEXT_DIRECTION_RTL);
toast.show();
```

You must change the TextDirection of the TextView that there is in the Toast's view.

Comment: While this may answer the OP's question, a few words of explanation would be helpful to current and future users, instead of just posting code. Also formatting your code would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Check this RTL toast library. Easy to use with many custom styles

[RTL-Toast](https://github.com/hatamiarash7/RTL-Toast/graphs/traffic)